# macro lvariable ist of character delimited by comma ONLY

Tags: sas

I have a question about passing a list of character string to sas as a macro variable.

I would like to go through a list of characters separated by commma:

Afghanistan,Angola,Burkina Faso,Azerbaijan

And I would like to print the country one by one like this in the log file of SAS:

Afghanistan
Angola
Burkina Faso
Azerbijan

This is my sas code ( I tried two things, one with %str(,) as the third argument in the %qscan function, the other is leaving out the third argument):

First thing that I tried:

```
%macro c2(countrylist);
        %let c = 0;
        %do %while(%qscan(&countrylist,&c+1, %str(,)) ne %str());
            %let c = %eval(&c+1); 
            %let countryname = %scan(&countrylist, &c);
            %put &countryname &c;
            %end;
%mend;
```

But somehow my code is not working, it is not treating comma as the ONLY delimiter, it is treating EITHER comma or a space as a delimiter. So I get something like this and with Azerbijan (the last in the character list) not being printed (for some reasons Azerbijan is not being looped through it seems)

Afghanistan
Angola
Burkina 
Faso

I already used the quoting function:  %str(,)
in my macro, but somehow still not working.

Second thing that I tried:

If I leave out %str(,) as the third argument in qscan, then I get:

Afghanistan
Angola
Burkina 
Faso
Azerbaijan

So Burkina and Faso are treated as separated entity (but Burkina and Faso should be printed together).

This is what I submitted to SAS:

```
%let pay = %str(Afghanistan,Angola,Burkina Faso,Azerbaijan);
%c2(&pay);
```

If anyone knows where my problem is, it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting the delimiter in the %SCAN() function call.  You did in the %QSCAN() call that you used in your %DO loop's %WHILE() condition test, but not in the line that actually pulls out the country name.

```
%macro c2(countrylist);
%local c countryname ;
%do c=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&countrylist,%str(,)));
  %let countryname = %scan(&countrylist, &c, %str(,));
  %put &countryname &c;
%end;
%mend;
```